# XMLhttprequest.send() doesn't send variables to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this code.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function removeAndReplace(id, sezione){
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
         alert(xhttp.responseText);
      }
   }

   xhttp.open("POST", "removeAndReplace.php", true);
   xhttp.send("id=" + id + "&sezione=" + sezione);
}
```

**PHP**

```
 print_r($_POST);

 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $sezione = $_POST['sezione'];
 .
 .
 .
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Elimina" class="btn_elimina" onClick="removeAndReplace(1, 'Shopping')">
```

I want to call a PHP function after the button click so I read that the better way is to use AJAX.

Firefox and Chrome return this error message:

> Array
>   (
>   )
>   
>   **Notice**:  Undefined index: id in **C:\pweb\tools\xampp\htdocs\Bazaar\php\removeAndReplace.php** on line **6**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Undefined index: sezione in **C:\pweb\tools\xampp\htdocs\Bazaar\php\removeAndReplace.php** on line **7**

Line 6 is: $id = $_POST['id'];
Line 7 is:  $sezione = $_POST['sezione'];

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you add a little more detail about how the function is called? Perhaps show the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dumping your data into the request body without telling the server how it is formatted.

Since PHP doesn't know you have sent it data in an encoding it understands, it ignores the request body.

You need to add:

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

… before you send the request.

---

*Aside*

While your hard coded data is free of special characters, it is best practice to encode your data. This will save you headaches in the future:

```
xhttp.send("id=" + encodeURIComponent(id) + "&sezione=" + encodeURIComponent(sezione));
```

---

You can save yourself the trouble of manually encoding the data and having to set your own content-type by using the FormData API:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("id", id);
data.append("sezione", sezione);

xhttp.open("POST", "removeAndReplace.php", true);
xhttp.send(data);
```